# Getting empty blob from MediaRecorder when Web Audio API is silent

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

I'm recording animated canvas (WebGL) and Web Audio API output together as a video using the `MediaRecorder` JS class. Everything works as expected if some audio is playing, but when not, then I get empty blob when stopping `MediaRecorder` instance.

Below is part of my code:

```js
const chunks = [];
var recorder = null, captureStream = null;

function dataAvailable(event) {
    chunks.push(event.data);
}

function startCapture() {
    const streamDestination = audio.context.createMediaStreamDestination();
    masterGain.connect(streamDestination);
    captureStream = canvas.captureStream();

    // This line adds audio to the recording if audio is playing
    // but if audio isn't playing at the moment, I get empty chunks
    // at the end of recording
    captureStream.addTrack(streamDestination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

    recorder = new MediaRecorder(captureStream);

    recorder.ondataavailable = dataAvailable;
    recorder.onstop = exportVideo;
    recorder.start();
}

function exportVideo() {
    // Here chunks will be empty if Web Audio API
    // didn't played anything during recording
    new Blob(chunks, {'type': 'video/webm'});
    ...
}
```

**How to get proper recording when Web Audio is silent?**

Using Chrome v92 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is https://crbug.com/1223382 that I did open a month ago, but which didn't got much traction since then.

Basically, they still have a lot of trouble dealing with muted tracks.

For a workaround, you could force your track to never be muted, by connecting an oscillator to a GainNode whose gain is set to `0`, and connect this GainNode to your destination stream.

```
const streamDestination = audio.context.createMediaStreamDestination();
const osc = audio.context.createOscillator();
const gainNode = audio.context.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 0;
osc.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(streamDestination);
// then your current code
masterGain.connect(streamDestination);
captureStream = canvas.captureStream();
...
```

[A fiddle with this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/fg7o4mx1/), fixing [my repro case from the bug report](https://jsfiddle.net/0zo7g8n9/).

*Caveats*:

- This isn't great for the trees, but compared to a WebGL animation and a live MediaRecorder, I guess it can be seen as a minimal cost.
- This will produce media files with an audio track, silent, but not muted.

---

Ps: you may also want to pass a (relatively small) time slice in `MediaRecorder.start(timeslice)` to workaround this [other related bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1172056), which could happen if for whatever reason one of your canvas or audio stream would get muted (e.g, if you stop drawing on your canvas for more than 5s).

Comment: Thank you for the details, I've implemented the workaround and it works for me.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but with no video. How would you implement that? Adding a black screen for example? Thanks

Comment: Many thanks to bring this up. I didn't even think about the muted attribute cause the issue. As you have mentioned in the bug report, `muted` is necessary for video autoplay. My customers don't like programmers change their settings surreptitiously. I have starred the bug as a vote. Hopefully we can have more attention in the near future.

Comment: Maybe related to [the bug I have reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1490888&q=mediarecord%20audiodestination&can=2#makechanges)